# VB.NET Webbrowser navigate to textbox1 + textbox2

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Need help VB code

Vb.net application using webbrowsercontrol

```
textbox1 = lastname = CLARKE

textbox2 = firstname = MARGARATE
```

navigate to preset webaddress while replacing lastname and firstname values of textbox1 and textbox2

This is the [web address](https://officialrecords.broward.org/oncoreV2/search.aspx?bd=1%2F1%2F1978&ed=4%2F26%2F2016&n=CLARKE%2CMARGARET&bt=O&d=4%2F26%2F2016&pt=-1&st=fullname&vbt=M)

last-name and first-name should be embedded as above link (clarke,margarete)

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Proof-read before posting! You have a typo in your example...

Comment: If you don't know how to concatenate a few substrings then I suggest that you spend some time reading a beginners tutorial or two before trying to do anything in anger.  We're here to help with problems, not teach you the fundamentals so that you don't have to try to learn them for yourself.